# cannot start hadoop namenode

Tags: linux, hadoop

I am following [this official site](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#Pseudo-Distributed_Operation) and I am sure I am doing all right. However, I cannot run sbin/start-dfs.sh for a Pseudo-Distributed node. 
Everytime I am getting the following error:

> starting namenodes on [localhost] 
>   pdsh@ML-Learning: localhost:connect: Connection refused 
>   starting datanodes 
>   pdsh@ML-Learning: localhost:connect: Connection refused 
>   starting secondary namenodes [ML-Learning] 
>   pdsh@ML-Learning: localhost:connect: Connection refused

I executed **ssh locaohost** without password.

Previously, I was able to run the following commands to start namenode and datanode.

```
bin/hadoop --daemon start namenode
bin/hadoop --daemon start datanode
```

However, I cannot stop them with the following commands, and the error is saying those daemons are running with process

```
bin/hadoop --daemon stop namenode
bin/hadoop --daemon stop datanode
```

So I was simply killing those processes, and it seems after that I ruined my whole set up. I cannot start namenode and datanode anymore.

```
bin/hadoop --daemon start namenode
bin/hadoop --daemon start datanode
```

It stuck in the following message:

> INFO blockmanagement.CacheReplicationMonitor: Starting CacheReplicationMonitor with interval 30000 milliseconds.

Any idea on this issue? I even restarted my VM, but the issue is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Remove Your current setup by formatting NameNode using,

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop namenode -format
```

Follow this without any failure,

```
  http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/
```

Comment: Thanks Deno. I will take a look at the article you pointed.

BTW,
I can run '$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop namenode -format' successfully.

Comment: Checkout the user and the permission. suppose if u installed hadoop as hduser then you cannot access hadoop commands using another user, Also checkout the permission for files/folders.

Comment: I follow the link you provided, however, I am running into the same issue.
"... localhost:connect: Connection refused"
All steps before start-hdfs.sh completed successfully. 
Have struggled with this issue for almost a week.
BTW, I am using Ubuntu 14.04LTS, and Hadoop 3.0.0

Answer (score 0):

run this command:
export PDSH_RCMD_TYPE=ssh